# Angular4 - how ngModel adds formControl and how to search in Angular source code?

Tags: angular

From the turotial:

> FormsModule gives us template driven directives such as ngModel

and:

> ReactiveFormsModule gives us directives like formControl

and:

> NgModel creates a new FormControl that is automatically added to the
>   parent FormGroup

So if I have an input that belongs to a `formGroup` object, I can add `ngModel` to it and `formControl` object will be created automatically. But `formControl` directive comes from **ReactiveFormsModule** and `ngModel` from **FormsModule**. So what actually happens is that these two modules communicates with each other? What if I don't import **ReactiveFormsModule**? `ngModel` will still have to look if there is **ReactiveFormsModule**, right? Isn't this inefficient?

I tried to dig in [Angular source](https://github.com/angular/angular), by trying to search in that repository something like - "FormsModule"; "export class FormsModule", got irrelevant results.

If anyone could give a link to Angular4 repo and some basic info how to search there, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/packages/forms

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L174

Comment: FormControl that belongs to ReactiveFormsModule has its own ngModel @input https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_name.ts#L91. And this input won't intersect with ngModel from FormsModule because see selector https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L107

Comment: @yurzui - thank you very much. Can you explain this line `[ngModel]:not([formControlName]):not([formControl])` Cant understand it at all...

Comment: It means select all elements with `ngModel` attribute but it should not have `formControlName` or `formControl` attribute

Comment: @yurzui - thanks a lot! That line confused me not the first time

Comment: `<input ngModel>` will be matched but not `<input formControlName ngModel>`

Comment: `<input ngModel>` - will be created `NgModel` directive from FormsModule, `<input formControlName ngModel>` - `FormControlName` directive from ReactiveFormsModule